# Cast smallint unsigned in Java

Tags: java, mysql, casting, jooq

I'm using jOOQ to get id which in MySQL is `smallint unsigned primary key auto_increment`

```
public List<Integer> getID() {
   Factory sql = new Factory(Database.getInstance().connect(), SQLDialect.MYSQL);
   return (List<Integer>) sql.select().from("users").fetch().getValues("id_users");
}
```

And go error

```
org.jooq.tools.unsigned.UShort cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

[Here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.java/html/java/java197.htm) they wrote that smallint unsigned should be cast to int.

**Edit**
Method should be

```
public List<UShort> getID() {
    Factory sql = new Factory(Database.getInstance().connect(), SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    return (List<UShort>) sql.select().from("users").fetch().getValues("id_users");
}
```

And in loop result should be cast to int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast UShort into Integer as it does not inherit that class. I guess you should use [`UShort.intValue()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/tools/unsigned/UShort.html#intValue%28%29) to retrieve the Integer.

Answer (score 1):

The java lang cannot cast that directly. You need am intermediate step.
Something like UShortval.intValue()
Iterate the result of the query, and build up a new List where you add the result of ushortval.intValue()

Answer (score 1):

If the `users` is a system table, thus you cannot change the type then you have to convert it to `Integer`. Otherwise you could change a table and provide `TINYINT(4)` for type `Short` Java.

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ can do the type casting and/or conversion for you. Here are a couple of examples:

```
Result<?> result = sql.select().from("users").fetch();

// Without any type information
List<?> list1 = result.getValues("id_users");

// Using your implicit knowledge about id_users being an unsigned short:
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<UShort> list2 = (List<UShort>) result.getValues("id_users");

// Using jOOQ's code-generator for type-safe field access:
List<UShort> list3 = result.getValues(USERS.ID_USERS);

// Using jOOQ's conversion features to convert UShort into whatever you prefer
List<Integer> list4a = result.getValues("id_users", Integer.class);
List<Integer> list4b = result.getValues(USERS.ID_USERS, Integer.class);
```

The last example being what you were probably looking for.

See the relevant Javadocs here:

- [`org.jooq.Result.getValues(Field, Class)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#getValues%28org.jooq.Field,%20java.lang.Class%29)
- [`org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Object, Class)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/tools/Convert.html#convert%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class%29)

Note that the link to the Sybase ASE manual is refering to a SQL cast operation, not a Java cast expression. That might have been what was misleading to you...